# Automated web based GUI testing tool

Tags: python, testing, user-interface, automation

Hi all i want to web based GUI Testing tool. I found dogtail is written using python. but i didnot get any good tutorial and examples to move further. Please Guide me weather dogtail is perfect or something better than this in python is there?. and if please share doc and example.

My requirement:
 A DVR continuous showing live video on tile(4 x 4 ), GUI is web based(mozilla) . i Should be able to swap video and  check log and have to compare actual result and present.

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you should take a look at Selenium and PhantomJS.

Comment: @Blender:selenium just record mouse movement and saves. how can i check log?

Comment: Selenium is entirely scriptable with Python. You're thinking of Selenium IDE.

Comment: @Blender: Do you have any links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) is designed exactly for this, it allows you to control the browser in Python, and check if things are as expected (e.g check if a specific element exists, submit a form etc)

There's [some more examples in the documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started.html)

[Project Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) is a similar tool, but is more general than just web-browsers

Answer (score 2):

Selenium provides a python interface rather than just record your mouse movements, see http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

If you need to check your video frames your can record them locally and OCR the frames looking for some expected text or timecode.

Answer (score 0):

For Simple form based UI Testing. I have created a framework using python/selenium/phantomjs although it can do complex stuff too. I am yet to document it. (If you don't need to run firefox you don't need to install phantomjs)

https://github.com/manav148/PyUIT