# Automate Oauth process of receiving Slack access token for Web API

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, slack, slack-api

I am working with the Slack oAuth API.

When I do a GET on https://slack.com/oauth/authorize passing my client_id, and the scope, I get html reponse asking for workspace URL.
After that I need to sign in and provide my password before `code` is returned which I can use to renew my temporary token

My question is: How can I automate the process of providing workspace URL, username and password? I need to get the code return after authentication (the temporary token) so that I can call `https://slack.com/api/oauth.access` to renew my token

My reasoning is that if I have access (from the app I created) to: `App ID`, `Client ID`, `Client Secret`, `Signing Secret` and `Verification Token` there should be a way for me make simple API call to get `code` or is my understanding of the slack OAuth flow wrong?

**NB:** I have taken a look at https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth but I was not able to get it done. I am also aware that I can make the `/signin` and `/checkcookie` to get this done but it involves parsing HTML response for parameter values needed to make subsequent calls. I just feel there a simpler way to do it.

This [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193395/slack-oauth-authorize-api-call)  is not a duplicate because is it mainly referred to a case of not having an app created; In my case, I have an app created.

Comment: Why do you want to automate the installation / Oauth process? It has to be done only once per Slack workspace and is meant to require a physical user to login with his credentials. The access tokens your app receives as result of that process never expires and should be stored by your app for future usage.

Comment: @Erik, I am doing this in a test environment for my interfacing application.  If I cannot automate the install process what would your alternative suggestions be? Thanks

Comment: Slack does not offer any special support for this approach. But if you want to automate the install process I would a web based testing tool of your choosing. Check out these references: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251016/automated-web-based-gui-testing-tool) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_testing_tools)